# How can I develop on Heroku using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git, heroku

I want to use XCode and git to pull-edit-push php code to Heroku.

I tried to create an empty XCode project with local git, then adding a remote to the local repository as git@heroku.com:.git with my Heroku user name and password. I wanted to pull the content from Heroku into the project and to perform usual project development tasks, like editing/adding files to project and pushing them back to Heroku, all within Xcode. However, when I try to pull, Xcode does not find the remote so I'm uanable to pull.
Can anyone help me with the correct setup?

Answer (score 0):

Did a heroku login from a terminal and used username and password in .netrc within Xcode. 'Push' worked within Xcode this way. Hopefully, "pull" works as well.